# regex validation not parsing string in if PHP

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

Here is the deal...

I am suppose to parse a Canadian Postal Code (CapsLetterNumberCapsLetterNumberCapsLetterNumber: exemple A1B2C3 or G2V3V4)
IF there is one.

I have this code (PHP):

```
//Create new SESSION variable to store a warning
$_SESSION['msg'] = "";
//IF empty do nothing, IF NOT empty parse, IF NOT match regex put message in msg
if(!preg_match('^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9])?$^', $_POST['txtPostalCode']) && $_POST['txtPostalCode'] != "")
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] .= "Warning invalide Postal Code";
}
```

then the code goes on to display `$_SESSION['msg']`.

The problem is that whatever I enter in $_POST['txtPostalCode'] it NEVER get parse by the REGEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made the entire capturing group optional:

```
^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9])?$^
                                 ^
```

It's also not a good idea to use regex metadata characters as your delimiter. Try this regex, which matches an uppercase letter and a number three times:

```
/^((?:[A-Z][0-9]){3})$/
```

You don't need to make the capturing group optional because you handle the logic for when the user doesn't submit a code with the `&& $_POST['txtPostalCode'] != ""` part of the if statement.

Finally, since you're not even using the matches from this regex, you don't need the capturing group:

```
/^(?:[A-Z][0-9]){3}$/
```

Comment: @AndréDion - Not according to the OP's specifications :) But, adding in space is a simple change.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex will match invalid postal codes.

A quick Google search for "canadian postal code regex" [bought up](http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx)

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$
```

You may also want to put your `$_POST['txtPostalCode'] != ""` condition first since there's no point in executing a regex if the value is empty to begin with.

**Edit:** As pointed out by the comments, the quantifiers are redundant:

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$
```

Comment: That, my friend, is an abomination of a regex. Someone, help me unsee it please. x_X P.S.: `^(?:[A-Z]\d){3}$`

Comment: @MaximKumpan - The functionality of yours and this one is different. Notice how in the first character class, `D` and other letters are missing. I suppose that is because they are not valid in Canadian postal codes.

Comment: Very well, but why the {1}? They are redundant, no? Also, you can use an exclude group to make it more readable.

Comment: Yes, the quantifiers are pointless. Simplified a bit: `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z]\s*\d[A-Z]\d$`

Comment: @AndréDion true, the letters are'nt all valid in Can Postal Code, did'nt think of it at first! If I could vote two answer I would! but nickb answers point out the `?` in my first expression. removing does resolve my problem but I will use your regex. Thanks to you two for your help !